# when create apk file error found ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: java, android, xml

When I am making apk file from my android for the first time.
I have this error.Can anyone help me?

**Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   BUILD FAILED in 4s
>   5 actionable tasks: 5 executed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually occurs due to the Gradle running in offline mode:-

Disable the offline mode of Gradle by going to File - Project Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Gradle - Remove --offline in Command Line options.(Or, simply click the -//- icon in the Gradle window.)

Then, connect to the internet and run Gradle build.

After the build has run once, you can enable the offline mode again.